# Enabling KVM for Android Emulator

Tags: kvm-virtualization, android-studio, android-emulator

I am using `Android Studio 4.0` and `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop` I have installed KVM from 
[here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation), but when i am using android Emulator, it lags.

How can i enable KVM for Android studio.

Processor: AMD Ryzen-5(3550-H) (Virtualization Enabled In BIOS)

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that's actually installed and usable:
**emulator -accel-check**

Also make sure that you're using hugepages and it's running. Check out this page:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KVM